# Angular $location is going back after change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm working with Angular and I need to redirect user to the view page after he submits the form.

I have attached following function to scope:

```
$scope.create = function () {
   return $scope.customer.$save({}, function (obj) {
       Msg.show('Customer created');
       return $location.path('customer/'+obj.id);
   })
};
```

This one works fine, user is redirected.

I've created a service to encapsulate the logic.

```
...
this.create = function (object, params, callback) {
    return function () {
        return object.$save(params, function (obj) {
            Msg.show('Object created');
            if ( callback instanceof Function ) {
                return callback(obj);
            }
        });
    };
};
....
```

So I attach it to the scope like this:

```
$scope.create = ResourceActions.create($scope.customer, {}, function (customer) {
    return $location.path('customers/'+customer.id);
});
```

After submit the user is "redirected" for only a blink of a second, then the path changes back. No idea what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that `After submit the user is "redirected" for only a blink of a second, then the path changes back.` ,so I think it should be redirect to a wrong path and then go to the **otherwise** branch:

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/**'
})
```

I suggest you recheck your `customer.id` if it maybe a undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change your $scope to:

```
$scope.create = ResourceActions.create($scope.customer, {}, function (customer) {
    $location.path('customers/'+customer.id);
});
```

Also, give a try  $state.go. For example, let's say you have this state:

```
.state('customers-details', {url: '/customers/:id'})
```

So, you could use $state.go like this:

```
$scope.create = ResourceActions.create($scope.customer, {}, function (customer) {
     $state.go('customers-details', {id: customer.id});
});
```

Remember, you have to inject $state in your controller.

bye